# Multiple EJB in single EAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a directory structure like this

```
- EAR
  - EJB 1
    - Class X
    - Class X Local Interface
  - EJB 2
    - Class Y
    - Class Y Local Interface
```

EJB 2 was added at a later date (By right clicking the EAR and selecting "Add Java EE Module")

In `Class X` I try to define `Class Y Local Interface` so I can instantiate a `Context lookup` but the compiler gives error, `cannot find symbol class YLocalInterface`

```
private YLocalInterface yBean = lookupYLocalInterface(); //fails
```

Entire project structure is like this

```
- EAR 1
  - EJB 1
    - Class X
    - Class X Local Interface
  - EJB 2
    - Class Y
    - Class Y Local Interface
  - WAR 1

- EAR 2
  - EJB 2
    - Class Y
    - Class Y Local Interface
  - WAR 2
```

I've added EJB 2 to EAR 1.

Comment: This seems to be purely classpath problem if this is a compiler-time error. How does your projects structure looks like? What IDE are you using?

Comment: @PiotrNowicki Using Netbeans. I edited original post

Comment: Do you have a project reference (in Netbeans) from EJB 1 to EJB 2? Can you check that EJB 2 project is in classpath of EJB 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your EJB project has a dependency on the other EJB project that it requires interfaces from.  So, for example if class X has a dependency on interface Y, you need to make sure that EJB1 has a reference to EJB2.  This is configured in the libraries settings for the project in NetBeans.

If you find that EJB1 calles EJB2 and EJB 2 calls EJB1, then you would need to extract out the  local interfaces into a separate jar that your EJB projects could then depend on instead of depending on the EJBs themselves.

Comment: Thank you this worked, but what is the point of adding an additional EJB to an EAR if all I had to do was add EJB 2 to EJB 1's libraries

Comment: As you have your project, it looks each EJB is in a separate jar file and is in a separate project.  This is why you need to add dependencies between the EJB projects.  Putting different EJB jars into an .Ear does not change their compile-time dependencies.  An .Ear file is used when you have more than one dependency that you wish to package together, such as 2 different EJB projects.